# Searching recursive data structure in C

Tags: c, recursion, tree

I would like help to write a recursive search function.

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
struct node_t {
    char       name[16];    
    int        num_children;
    node_t**   children;
};
```

and I have many nodes in a deep tree-like structure, where each node can have many children.

To find a node somewhere in the tree, I currently pass the root node to this function:

```
node_search(node_t* parent, const char* node_name) {

    if(strcmp(parent->name, node_name) == 0) {
        return parent;
    } 
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < parent->num_children; ++i) {
            node_t* node_found = node_search(parent->children[i], node_name);

            if(strcmp(node_found->name, node_name) == 0) {
                return node_found;
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work, but two things I have observed make me worry that this is not the best/correct way to do this:

1. When the desired node is found very deep in the tree, the `strcmp` is done for each frame in the call stack on the way out of the recursion.
2. When traversing a branch in the tree that doesn't have the desired node, the `strcmp` inside the loop ends up doing its compare on garbage values, which just doesn't feel very solid.

Does anybody know it this recursive search could be done in a better way?

Comment: Hint: You should use `NULL` to your advantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a return value on all paths, and addressing that warning that your compiler *should* have given you will lead you to understand `NULL` is the only logical alternative when nothing is found.

With that, you can *significantly* reduce the code by eliminating redundant checks while fixing this. You don't need two `strcmp` here. You mentioned in your bullet list: "...the strcmp inside the loop..." - you already *have* a `strcmp` in the loop; it's done in the recursed call for that child. There is no sense in doing it again.

```
node_t* node_search(node_t* parent, const char* node_name)
{
    if(strcmp(parent->name, node_name) == 0)
        return parent;

    node_t *node_found = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; !node_found && i < parent->num_children; ++i)
        node_found = node_search(parent->children[i], node_name);

    return node_found;
}
```

That should return NULL if the element is not found, and break the loop, returning up the chain as soon as a node *is* found.

Finally, depending on the location of this code, you *might* want to ensure `parent` isn't NULL before that opening dereference. This code assumes it is never called without a valid, non-null pointer for `parent`. Whether or not that is a valid assumption (it was in your posted code, apparently) I leave for you to decide.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should return `NULL` outside the loop.

Inside the loop you should check if the returned value is not `NULL`, if it's not then an inner frame has already compared it for you, so just break the loop and return the same value.

So:

```
if (node_found != NULL)
  return node_found;
```